# How to do Partial Response with Google URL Shortener API

Tags: google-api

Looking at the documentation on this API there is a page on performance to cut back the number of keys in the JSON dictionary returned.  [URL Shortener Performance Tips](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/performance)

Of the three dictionary keys returned in the insert request of this API, I am only interested in the shortened URL.  The *id* key.   Looking at the above documentation I would have expected this to work:

The POST request https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?fields=id?key=YOUR-API-KEY

But with the *fields=id* added the request comes back invalid.

How do you set only a partial response for this API to only return the *id* key?

Comment: `fields=id` works fine with the [docs try it tool](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url/insert#try-it). Personally I wouldn't worry about it though. Unless you are making a billion requests a day the bandwidth savings is going to be minimal.

Comment: that tool uses OAuth 2.0, and I do not use that mechanism in my app.  Just the API key approach.  Perhaps a limitation that is not documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the comment from abraham steered me in the right direction on this problem.  I was able to find the Try it tool option without OAuth and it worked also to my surprise.  Looking at the request it generated I found that it was a  syntax error on my part looking at the url given in my original question.   It should be:

`?fields=id&`

not

`?fields=id?`